# Select NULL values from SQL Server table

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, asp.net-mvc-4

I am working with ASP.NET MVC 4 using C# and SQL Server

I am selecting a row of data from the following table

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Mem_Basic] (
[Id]          INT           IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
[Mem_NA]      VARCHAR (100) NOT NULL,
[Mem_Occ]     VARCHAR (200) NOT NULL,
[Mem_Role]    VARCHAR (200) NOT NULL,
[Mem_Email]   VARCHAR (50)  NULL,
[Mem_MPh]     VARCHAR (15)  NULL,
[Mem_DOB]     DATE          NULL,
[Mem_BGr]     NCHAR (10)    NULL,
[Mem_WAnn]    DATE          NULL,
[Mem_Spouse]  VARCHAR (75)  NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
);
```

using the following code

```
public MemberBasicData GetMemberProfile(int id)
{
        MemberBasicData mb = new MemberBasicData();
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(Config.ConnectionString))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Mem_Basic WHERE Id="+id+"", con))
            {
                try
                {
                    con.Open();
                    SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                   if(reader.Read()==true)
                    {
                        mb.Id = (int)reader["Id"];
                        mb.Mem_NA = (string)reader["Mem_NA"];
                        mb.Mem_Occ = (string)reader["Mem_Occ"];
                        mb.Mem_Role = (string)reader["Mem_Role"];
                        mb.Mem_Email = (string)reader["Mem_Email"];
                        mb.Mem_MPh = (string)reader["Mem_MPh"];
                        mb.Mem_DOB = (Convert.ToDateTime(reader["Mem_DOB"]));
                        mb.Mem_BGr = (string)reader["Mem_BGr"];
                        mb.Mem_WAnn = (Convert.ToDateTime(reader["Mem_WAnn"]));
                        mb.Mem_Spouse = (string)reader["Mem_Spouse"];
                   }
                }
                catch (Exception e) { throw e; }
                finally { if (con.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Open) con.Close(); }
            } 
        }
        return mb;
    }
```

This shows the error

> Unable to cast object of type 'System.DBNull' to type 'System.String'.

(`Mem_Email`, `MPh`.. etc sometimes contain a `NULL` value.. if the value is null I want return null). Anybody please help me.

Comment: Unrelated to your question (as you have an answer below) but your try, catch and finally are all redundant. Catching and throwing is pointless (and will truncate the stack trace in the way you have implemented it), and the finally is closing the connection even though your use of the `using` statement will handle that for you already.

Comment: Using a connector or ORM would help a lot here. Personally, when I hear "C#" and "SQL Server", I think Entity Framework, but there are plenty of alternatives.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just make some short if, you should do the same for all the other variables:

```
 mb.Mem_Email = reader["Mem_Email"] == System.DBNull.Value ? null : (string) reader["Mem_Email"];
```

Answer (score 3):

You could save yourself a serious amount of pain here with a tool like dapper (http://www.nuget.org/packages/Dapper):

```
public MemberBasicData GetMemberProfile(int id)
{
    using (var con = new SqlConnection(Config.ConnectionString))
    {
        return con.Query<MemberBasicData>(
            "SELECT * FROM Mem_Basic WHERE Id=@id",
            new { id } // full parameterization, done the easy way
        ).FirstOrDefault();
    }
}
```

things this does:

- does correct parameterization (for both performance and safety), but without any inconvenience
- does all the materialization, handling nulls (both in parameters and columns) for you
- is insanely optimized (basically, it is measurably the same speed as writing all that code yourself, except fewer things to get wrong)

Comment: how can i return a model by using this

Comment: @Parvathiiiii the code above **shows** how you return a model by using this. It does *precisely that*. Basically, the `Query<T>` method materializes each row found into an instance of `T` via `IEnumerable<T>` (i.e. per row); from there we can use LINQ if we want, so the `FirstOrDefault` gets us from `IEnumerable<T>` to `T`.

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively to King King's answer you can write code like this:

```
mb.Mem_Email = reader["Mem_Email"] as string;
```

For value types, if the column allows nulls, it's a good practice to map them to nullable value types in C# so that this code `reader["Mem_DOB"] as DateTime?` works

Answer (score 0):

Change for all columns, that might be NULL from this

```
mb.Mem_NA = (string)reader["Mem_NA"];
```

to that

```
mb.Mem_NA = reader["Mem_NA"].ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

**Treat the nullable fields:**

```
mb.Mem_Email = System.DBNull.Value.Equals(reader["Mem_Email"])?"":
                                      (string)reader["Mem_Email"];
```

**Do** the same for:
mb.Mem_MPh, mb.Mem_BGr and mb.Mem_Spouse.

Answer (score 0):

I don't mean to sound like a SQL bigot (which of course means I *DO* mean to sound like a SQL bigot), but if you followed SQL best practices and used a column list instead of SELECT * you could resolve this problem by using COALESCE on the nullable columns thus:

```
SELECT
  [Id],
  [Mem_NA],
  [Mem_Occ],
  [Mem_Role],
  COALESCE( [Mem_Email], '' ) AS [Mem_Email],
  COALESCE( [Mem_MPh], '' ) AS [Mem_MPh],
  COALESCE( [Mem_DOB], CAST( '1753-1-1' AS DATE ) ) AS [Mem_DOB],
  COALESCE( [Mem_BGr, '' ) AS [Mem_BGr],
  COALESCE( [Mem_WAnn], CAST( '1753-1-1' AS DATE ) ) AS [Mem_WAnn],
  COALESCE( [Mem_Spouse], '' ) AS [Mem_Spouse]
FROM 
  [dbo].[Mem_Basic];
```

Your c# code can now dependably process the result set without having to account for outliers (the exception being the dates; you should probably check for whatever default you use in the COALESCE for those (I used the minimum allowable value for a SQL Date variable in the above example), and handle them appropriately.

Additionally, you can get rid of the finally block in your c# code.  You wrapped the connection in a "using" block; it will automatically close the connection when you go out of scope (that is the purpose of the "using" block).